# making multivariate GAM model

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to create a model that will fit my data. For example this one:

```
N=100
c=rbinom(N, 1, 0.2)
H=rnorm(N, -10, 2)
A=1.4*c+0.6+H
B=1.5*c^2+0.8/H
Y=cbind(A,B)
```

so I have a matrix of Y that have two columns (A,B), by this I want to represent the interaction between A and B. I want to model the dependence of Anad B based on two variables c and H:

```
fmla=Y~s(c)+s(H)
library("mgcv", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library")
```

And I want to fit it with GAM model

```
gam(fmla)
```

However, it cant do it because Y is a matrix of two variables, and GAM does not like it. So I guess I just don't know a proper syntax here

Comment: Why not fit two models with univariate outcomes?

Comment: I thought that it will model A and B independently from each other. But I want to include that value of A may be dependant on B, by modeling them together in one model

Comment: The linear model version  would allow for `cbind()` but it doesn't fit a correlation/covariance term - they're just separate linear models IIRC. **mgcv** allows for a multivariate normal response where formulas give linear predictors for the mean vector of the MVN and as part of fitting a covariance term is also estimated. As I show in my answer, the way to fit that model requires a list of $d$ formulas, one per response variable. See `?mvn` and `?formula.gam`

Answer (score 4):

In **mgcv** you need to specify this via a list of formulas and use the `mvn()` family, for example:

```
gam(list(Y1 ~ X1 + s(X2),
         Y2 ~ X1 + s(X2)),
    data = my_data_frame, family = mvn(d = 2))
```

For the example in your question you want something like:

```
N <- 100
C <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.2)
H <- rnorm(N, -10, 2)
A <- 1.4*C+0.6+H
B <- 1.5*C^2+0.8/H

df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = factor(C), H = H)

library('mgcv')

m <- gam(list(A ~ C + s(H),
              B ~ C + s(H)),
         data = df, family = mvn(d = 2))
```

(That doesn't actually work - I think because of poor choice of starting values for model parameters.)

Note you can't fit a smooth of `C` because there are only two values possible — 0 and 1 — so above I converted `C` to a factor variable and included it as a linear parametric effect.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeh i guess my choice of fummy parameters was very poor to produce any meaningfull results. But thanks for clarifying how to imput my paranters. So am I right that in the case even though A and B are modeled in separate equations, the model will take into account their interaction with each other?

Comment: They have separate linear predictors, and "interaction" isn't the right word, but yes, the model will estimate the covariance or correlation between the responses.